# Discussion on the implementation of read function for a 2D BIT

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

I recently read about ***2D Binary Indexed Trees***  from
 ( ***http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees***)

in order to solve a question on Codeforces,
      (  ***http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/341/D*** )
As can be seen , the question looks for **intermixed Update and Read Operations** on a 2 Dimensional fixed size array.

While implementing the functions for the *2D BIT*, I implemented the read function by myself, and found the update function on Topcoder.

In the read function, I have applied the *extension to a* **1D BIT** by reading the tree (of responsibility ) at that point to get a cumulative frequency from **(1,1)** uptil **(x,y)**, and then in order to remove the values not required, I repeatedly **XOR** with the rectangular portions whose values I do not require inorder to eliminate them.

The regions in choice 1 , I read are the subrectangle **(1,1,x1,y1)**, which I subsequently then  ***XOR*** with all values within the two subrectangles **(1,1,x0-1,y1)** and **(1,1,x1,y0-1)**. The 2 subrectangles are themselves being subjected to read operations. Then since the subrectangle **(1,1,x0-1,y0-1)** is being ***XORed*** an odd number of times, I XOR the result with a final read operation to **(1,1,x0-1,y0-1)**. This according to me should be the standard approach to this problem. Where am I faltering in this, and more importantly am I implementing any functon incorrectly?

Please throw some insight into any error, as I am not making any headway.

P.S.: When I display the tree[][] , it is displaying correctly, I am not getting why is the  answer being reported incorrect.

The link to my solution ( at ideone ) is : **http://ideone.com/vJIxHZ**

and the attached code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
ll tree[1002][1002];
using namespace std;
ll read(ll x,ll y,ll n)
{
    ll sum=0;
    while(x>0 )
    {
        ll y1=y;
        while(y1>0)
        {
            sum ^= tree[x][y1];
            y1-=(y1&-y1);
        }
        x-=(x&-x);
    }
    return sum;
}
void update(ll x , ll y , ll val, ll n){
    ll y1;
    while (x <= n){
        y1 = y;
        while (y1 <= n){
            tree[x][y1] ^= val;
            y1 += (y1 & -y1); 
        }
        x += (x & -x); 
    }
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    #define int long long int
    int n,m,x0,y0,x1,y1,v;
    //scanf("%I64d%I64d",&n,&m);
    cin>>n>>m;
/*  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
    {
        tree[i][j]=0;
    } */
    while(m--)
    {
        int choice;
        //scanf("%I64d",&choice);
        cin>>choice;
        if(choice==1)
        {
            //scanf("%I64d%I64d%I64d%I64d",&x0,&y0,&x1,&y1);
            cin>>x0>>y0>>x1>>y1;
            cout<<(read(x1,y1,n)^read(x0-1,y1,n)^read(x1,y0-1,n)^read(x0-1,y0-1,n))<<"\n";
            //printf("%I64d\n",
        }
        else
        {
        //  scanf("%I64d%I64d%I64d%I64d%I64d",&x0,&y0,&x1,&y1,&v);
            cin>>x0>>y0>>x1>>y1>>v;
            update(x0,y0,v,n);
            update(x0,y1+1,v,n);
            update(x1+1,y0,v,n);
            update(x1+1,y1+1,v,n);
        }
    }
/*  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
     {
        cout<<read(i,j,n)<<" ";

     }
     cout<<"\n";
    } */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define int long long int`? Don't do this again, *ever!* Especially since you already have the `ll` alias (which is cryptic enough). Why not just use `int64_t`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I was using it only in the hope of an Accepted, lest the code suffers from integer overflows, I know it is quite ambiguous and thanks for pointing this, but could you please elaborate on the implementation details. I know how to implement 1D BIT where updation is from x to y, and query also from x to y, but 2D BIT operations are somewhat trickier I presume!

Comment: I think you are missing the point here...you are supposed to xor all the values in x0,y0 x1,y1 with a value v.  For that you do not have to read the values in 1,1 x1,y1 if you do that, there is no point in using a BIT. You build a bit or even better a segment tree so you can do interval queries efficiently...that means not read all the values in the give interval but get them by accessing the nodes of the tree...